# chown not working on remote filesystem, other commands (e.g., chmod) do work

Tags: mount, permissions, filesystem, chown

I am trying to change the ownership of a file on a remote filesystem,
but chown responds with

```
chown: changing ownership of ‘foo’: No such file or directory
```

However, as you can see, foo is there and I can do other operations on
it.  For example, `sudo chmod a+x foo` works just fine.  E.g.,

```
prompt> ls -l foo
-rw-rw-r-- 1 debug debug 0 Dec  4 09:45 foo
prompt> sudo chmod a+w foo
prompt> ls -l foo
-rw-rw-rw- 1 debug debug 0 Dec  4 09:45 foo
prompt> sudo chown seth foo
chown: changing ownership of ‘foo’: No such file or directory
prompt> ls -l foo
-rw-rw-rw- 1 debug debug 0 Dec  4 09:45 foo
```

The directory lives on a remote drive mounted as follows:

```
sudo mount //10.71.165.126/seth /mnt/centraldrive -o user=name,pass=password
```

The remote filesystem is a seagate central.
I am running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS.

Any help would be appreciated.

[A side note, I created foo with `sudo touch foo`.  However, for some
reason the ownership is given the the `debug` user.  Is that related?]

Comment: Are you wanting to change the permissions on the Seagate or the local mount point? And are you using valid login credentials for the Seagate in your `mount` command rather than you local machine credentials? Makes a difference.

Comment: Mount command is using credentials for seagate.  Trying to run `chown` on the seagate.

Comment: If you want to change permissions on the Seagate, you'll have to `ssh` into it and change them there. You're creating a mount point for the Seagate locally in `/mnt/centraldrive` and file permissions won't "stick" there unless you create a directory in `/mnt` and specifically mount the Seagate with an `fstab` entry that contains the user/group assigned to the mount point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion of douggro I was able to get things done properly, even without an entry in fstab:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //ip-adr-of-seagate/user /mnt/centraldrive -o username=user,pass=password,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```